# How can I achieve this design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

http://www.awwwards.com/websites/single-page/

It's called bad assembly, located at the bottom of the page

Okay so I'm trying to achieve the design (desktop view) you see above but my pictures keep overflowing. I could just hide the [overflow-y](/questions/tagged/overflow-y) but I don't want to do that. My CSS is just Bootstrap, by the way. I was thinking about making 3 sections on each row that each has a width of 33% with a [background-image](/questions/tagged/background-image) but it's getting late. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<Img src="...#>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <Img src="...#>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
 <Img src="...#>
 </div>

 </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<Img src="...#>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <Img src="...#>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
 <Img src="...#>
 </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn'tget you exactly what you want...

According to your question.. i can suggest... instead of using img tag Use Background Image.

Set background image in a class or place it with your coloumn div.

Make sure that Image is exact the same size as of column.

Thanks.